# Linking static libraries

Tags: iphone, static-libraries, ios5, automatic-ref-counting, ios-frameworks

I have a project that uses several static libraries and I keep getting errors like this one:

```
ld: duplicate symbol _deg2Rad in Frameworks/MyFramework.embeddedframework/
MyFramework.framework/MyFramework(MyFramework) and Frameworks/
MyFramework.embeddedframework/MyFramework.framework/MyFramework(MyFramework) for 
architecture armv7

Command /***/Development/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/
usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

I assume that it has something to do with ARC which I use as well in my project as in the library stated in the error. The stated library furthermore uses one static library that has NOT enabled ARC. My deployment target is 4.3. The libraries are deployed on iOS 5.0.

I had the libs deployed on 4.3 before but I got similar errors with _objc_retainedObj instead of _deg2Rad.

Any help is very much appreciated! What else information might help someone solving this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your static libraries use the same function (i.e. deg2Rad) and you are getting this...

Unfortunately although those providing Static Libraries should custom Prefix all their functions, however they do not do, so you end up in those situations...

Solution is to contact them and ask them to custom prefix their functions and variables that are exposed by their .h files...

Comment: Yep. That was the reason. I have no idea why I got the other/similar warnings before but there was a function named like the framework function deg2rad. I renamed it and everything was fine. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

In your compiler flags configuration, do you have `-ObjC -all_load`?  Try adding those to your project's target.  Then clean and rebuild.  I've had that problem as well sometimes and it was usually because I forgot those flags.

Comment: Thx for the hint. I really forgot those, but adding them didnt help D:

Comment: It also can depend sometimes on #imports.  For some reason, if you #import the same file more than once, but in the same "hierarchy", you will get those errors.  I know #import is not supposed to duplicate things, but it's weird.

Answer (score 0):

Forgetting to adjust the framework search path is another reason for having problems with building frameworks.